# Request to rename the [corb] tag to [marklogic-corb]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I propose renaming the [corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corb) tag to 'marklogic-corb'. The current definition of the tag relates to a MarkLogic-specific tool for processing content, but it also stands for [Cross-Origin Read Blocking](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768). I've seen several questions using this tag intending the latter sense of the word (I've removed the tag). Changing the name to [marklogic-corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marklogic-corb) will

1. Make the intent of this tag clear
2. Follow the pattern of other MarkLogic-related tags
3. Follow the precedent of other tags related to specific databases
4. Allow someone else to create a new [corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corb) tag for the web-related use.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that acronyms are inherently confusing, and that this does deserve a tag rename. As for point 4, the tag [cross-origin-read-blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-origin-read-blocking) *already* exists, and should have been used for the CORB related questions, instead of the [corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corb) which was for the CoRB related questions.

I went through all the 23 questions tagged [corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corb) and checked if they were related to the MarkLogic CoRB, or not. I retagged/closed the ones that were not.

The tag is now renamed. In order to prevent the recreation of [corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corb), I synonymized it with [marklogic-corb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marklogic-corb).